# How do I list MVC users and their roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles, asp.net-identity

I need to list all the users with their roles (one role per user) using my code in the admin panel. Something that will be so easily done in SQL like so:

```
select u.FirstName, u.LastName, r.Name
from dbo.AspNetUsers u
left join dbo.AspNetUserRoles ur on u.Id = ur.UserId
left join dbo.AspNetRoles r on ur.RoleId=r.Id
```

or it can be done by reading the role of the user when iterating them (not just the logged one), but I can't do that as well.

Comment: this doesn't actually have anything to do with `identity`

Comment: it is all about the identity. I'm facing this problem because of that. Identity is how the Users and the roles are created by. http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: @user3631624 You used the wrong tag you wanted [tag:asp.net-identity].

Comment: I'm sorry, so what's "identity" used for, then?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use UserManager.GetRoles(userId) to get the role names that the user is a member of.